# How to use makeStyles in latest material-ui version 5 in React

Tags: material-ui, makestyles

I am using Material Ui version 5.2.7. When I import makeStyles from @mui/materials/styles, I am getting following error -

Uncaught Error: MUI: makeStyles is not longer exported from @mui/material/styles. You have to import it from @mui/styles. See https://mui.com/r/migration-v4/#material-ui-core-styles for more details.

At also says that @mui/styles is deprecated in mui version 5. So I am confused how I can import makeStyles. Anyone have any idea on this?

I am using Material Ui version 5.2.7. When I import makeStyles from @mui/materials/styles, I am getting following error -

Uncaught Error: MUI: makeStyles is not longer exported from @mui/material/styles. You have to import it from @mui/styles. See https://mui.com/r/migration-v4/#material-ui-core-styles for more details.

At also says that @mui/styles is deprecated in mui version 5. So I am confused how I can import makeStyles. Anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

As Error says

1. install

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styles
or
yarn add @mui/material @mui/styles
```

2. import

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```